# WindowsPhone - Como dispara um evento "dentro" de outro?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, eventos, xaml

Defini a visibilidade de minha combobox como Collapsed,  por questões visuais e visto que o AppBarButton é mais apresentavel. Quero saber se é possivel chamar o evento do combobox através do disparo do evento de um AppBarButton?

Algo como:

```
      private void teste_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
     private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {   ...

    }  }
```

ou

```
    <AppBarButton x:Name="teste" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Undo" Label="" Margin="11.5,12,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="combobox1_SelectionChanged" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Comment: Pra que chamar dentro? Que eu saiba, quando um elemento passa a ser visível, todos os eventos associados a ele passam a valer, não precisando colocar um evento dentro do outro. Caso você queira atribuir o evento dinamicamente, basta colocar: `meuObjeto_MeuHandler += Nome_Do_Handler;`

Answer (score 3):

Como o SelectionChanged e o Click são eventos com parâmetros diferentes, você não pode chamar da 2a forma que você mostrou, via XAML. Você pode, se lhe couber, chamar o método dentre de outro método, da seguinte forma:

```
private void teste_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    combobox1_SelectionChanged(this, null);
}

private void combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

e seu XAML ficaria assim:

```
    <AppBarButton x:Name="teste" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Icon="Undo" Label="" Margin="11.5,12,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="teste_click" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Neste caso eu estou passando null no "SelectionChangedEventArgs e", portanto se você estava usando "e" para alguma coisa, vai jogar uma exception. De qualquer forma, para reaproveitar este código, é assim que pode ser feito.
Se você estiver usando o argumento "e" e quiser fazer funcionar, ai vai dar um pouco mais de trabalho. Em vez de passar null na chamada do método, passe new SelectionChangedEventArgs(...), sendo que terá que passar as listagens de itens adicionados e removidos, mas não creio que este seja seu caso.